# Which layout is used for clash of clans home screen? We can scroll it horizontal as well as vertical. Please illuminate

Tags: android, xml

Any Clash of Clans players here?
Please excuse me if I am over the board here
Can you tell me which android layout [Is it frameLayout?] is used in Clash of Clans game. We can scroll the screen horizontal as well as vertical. We can pinch magnify the screen as well.

Any nudge to the right article or relevant must reads is appreciated as well.

[image: clash of clans home village]
![clash of clans home village][1]

Comment: It's not made using Android layouts. Most games are not as they would use some game engine.
It appears they use their own engine written in C++ ([link](https://www.quora.com/What-3D-engine-does-the-Clash-of-Clans-mobile-game-use))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a layout being rendered by an engine, as answered by @RobCo in the comments. What you might want to do is using a game engine, and there are pretty good ones out there:

https://unity3d.com/

Standard XML layouts in Android are mostly for textViews, images and buttons. Not rendering 3D. You can also try to implement some OpenGL in your app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Comment: Thank you Giovanni Terlingen. Because of you I know that there exists something called NDK developers for android framework. Cheers man!!